# Can you disable finding and displaying Media Devices in W10 Network Explorer?

Tags: windows-10

The Desktop icon named Network, when opened, will display a list of Media Devices -- like DIRECTV DVRs -- found on the LAN. In recent versions of Windows 10, like v1703 and v1709, is it possible to delete them and keep them from being found later? Even better, can scanning for these devices be disabled, without disabling network discovery?

Answer (score 0):

No, if you don’t want to see the media devices or computers in Network explorer, you need to turn off network discovery in current network profile.

If you just want to remove some media devices,  type Media  into the start search box.

Click on Media Streaming options from the list. From the pulldown menus, block the ones you don't want.

Comment: Thank you for replying @Origami. Media Streaming is turned off and yet Media Devices is heavily populated with every DIRECTV box and similar device on the LAN.  To what extent will disabling network discovery impact sharing printers and files?